# How to solve $2^n\leq (en)^C$

Tags: calculus, inequality

I am wondering how to solve the equation $2^n\leq (en)^C$
 and reach the solution $n\leq 2Clog_{2}(eC)$?

By taking $log_{2}$, we get $n \leq Clog_{2}(en)$, what next?

Comment: Taking $\log_2$.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla how can I get n out of $log(n)$ after taking log?

Comment: $n\leq 2Clog_{2}(eC)$ is **not** the solution.

Comment: I read that from a paper, without a proof. So what is the solution?

Comment: I'm saying that $n\leq 2Clog_{2}(eC)$ isn't equivalent to $2^n\leq (en)^C$.

Comment: Right. So how can I find the upper bound of $n$?

Answer (score 0):

Idea, too long for a comment:
$$n\le C\log_2(en)\le C\log_2(eC\log_2(en)) = C\log_2(eC) + C\log_2(\log_2(en))\le\cdots$$
and continue applying the first inequality until $\log_2(\cdots\log_2(en)\cdots)\le 0$

Comment: I wonder if "$en$" is supposed to be "$e^n$".